# Grepping a file for flags ( -i -d -p -a etc)

Tags: bash, grep, arguments

So lets say I have a shell script and this is its contents:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "/bin/bash -p" && echo "Pretty Power of zeus Pouring down thunder"
```

For example when I grep this: `cat test.sh | grep 'p'` it will return just the `-p` in `/bin/bash -p`.

Why is that? I'm assuming because it's the first instance of `p` occurring but not exactly sure.

Comment: use this ``` and this ``` around code, look for the regex for "line ending in"

Comment: test.sh contains only one `p`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep --ignore-case` or `grep -i` will be case insensitive. I didn't know it was case sensitive by default.